Html number input handling in blazor
I am facing issue in handling max with manual input. My implementation works like: when input value is already equal to max like 13 equal to  13 and I enter more value it becomes i.e 136. I am trying to convert to 13 but its work only for 2 digits length, like 20 converted into 13 but after it becomes 134 or 137
<td>
    <input min="0.01" class="quantityInput"
           type="number" step="0.01" 
           value="@item.Quantity"   
           @oninput="e => UpdateQuantity(item,e)"
           max="@item.MaxQuantity" />
</td>

@code {
   private void UpdateQuantity(EditableSaleItemViewModel item, ChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       var input = e.Value?.ToString();

       if (double.TryParse(input, out double newQuantity))
       {
           if (newQuantity < 0)
           {
               newQuantity = 0; // Ensure it's not negative
           }
           else if (newQuantity > item.MaxQuantity)
           {
               newQuantity = item.MaxQuantity;  
           }
        
           item.Quantity = newQuantity;
           e.Value = item.Quantity;
           item.TotalPrice = Math.Round(item.Quantity * item.UnitPrice, 2);
       }
       else
       {
           item.Quantity = 0;  
           item.TotalPrice = 0;
       }

       totalAmount = Math.Round(editableSaleItems.Sum(i => i.TotalPrice), 2);
       StateHasChanged();
   }
}


The code itself causes problems - it's trying to parse the input value using the application's culture, even though input type=numeric controls always use . as the decimal separator. I'd suggest using Blazor's Input components like InputNumber<TValue with min/max values, and let Blazor do the parsing. Even better, use model binding and add validation as annotations to the model. Blazor will generate the appropriate validation code

in my implimentation the values updated to maxvalue when input  value is heigher when i use debugger ,other wise its partialy works ,only single case for which that not works is inputvalue is alredy max and still enter value

I can't create a Minimal Reproducible Example from your code, so here's a demo of how you could implement your input using binding.
<input class="form-control"
       type="number"
       step="0.01"
       @bind:get="_quantity"
       @bind:set="this.SetQuantity"
       @bind:event="oninput" />


@code {
    private decimal _quantity;
    private decimal _maxQuantity = 20;

    private void SetQuantity(decimal value)
    {
        _quantity = value;

        if (value > _maxQuantity)
            _quantity = _maxQuantity;

        if (value < 0)
            _quantity = 0;

            //Add other logic you want
    }
}


yes ,your 2 way binding solved my issue .thanks

i mentioning documention link that may helps  future viewers that face same issue...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-bindgetbindset-modifiers-and-avoid-event-handlers-for-two-way-data-binding

I had a similar problem by creating a numerical combobox. the problem is in blazor there are two different way to manage onchange, but they will be mixed easily and cause confiusion. this link helped me to undrestand the problem
https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/value-changed-validation-model
my suggestion is that change @oninput="e => UpdateQuantity(item,e)" to ValueChanged="CustomerHasChangedEvent" and add ValueExpression="@((@item.Quantity)=> )". when you use @oninput you need @bind-value as well.... your tag should seems something like this
 <input min="0.01" class="quantityInput"
        type="number" step="0.01" 
        value="item.Quantity"
        ValueChanged="UpdateQuantity"
        ValueExpression="@(()=>item.Quantity)"
        max="@item.MaxQuantity" />

so directly you can work with numbers instead of converting string-number.
